# Saltstack set variables after a state

Tags: salt-stack, exim4

I have a question about SaltStack variables.
I want to set a folder name, something like:

```
{% set exim4_folder = salt['cmd.run']('ls /tmp | grep exim4') %}
```

but the folder I am trying to get is not available till the state I ran before that assignment:

```
download_source_code:
  cmd.run:
    - cwd: /tmp
    - names:
      - apt-get -y source exim4
      - apt-get -y build-dep exim4
```

Is there a way to tell salt to run that assignment after I run "download_source_code"?

Comment: Try splitting it into two different states, and `include` the prerequisite one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're going to run into here is that all the jinja sections of your sls file will be evaluated before any of the yaml Salt states are evaluated.

So your 'ls /tmp | grep exim4' will always be executed before your `download_source_code` state is executed.